# Site logo link incorrect after url change

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've changed the url of a site and now when we click the logo it still links to the old url which gives a 404 error. Same for the site title.

When I hover the logo or the title the link is correct. Once clicked it opens the wrong link.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your issue per my rest.

Clear the browser cache and compare the result.

If the issue still exists, open the site in inprivate window then check the result.